How to get the ink! examples working
I have been banging my head in over the last couple of days trying to understand Rust and ink!
I would really like to start writing smart contracts in the substrate ecosystem but I can't even get the examples to work.
I am following https://github.com/use-ink/ink-examples but other then the flipper example on the substrate page nothing works at all.
What are the exact steps to get the contract-transfer example working? I use cargo contract build deploy it to my substrate node and then start the frontend with pnpm contract-transfer but nothing happens.
the only thing I want to do is call some extrinsics on the polkadot realy chain for a XCM transfer.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
